# Windows Mobile 6.5 Authentication Soap Header

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6.5

How do you add a username/password to a `Soap` header via a `Windows Mobile 6.5` application for an outbound web service call?

I have successfully achieved this in the full `.Net` framework by specifying the `SoapExtension` in the `App.Config/Web.Config` file but this does not exist in the compact framework.

edit:
a bit more info.

i have a web service which was supplied by a third party so i dont have the code to it and i couldnt tell you what happens within it.  However, when i add a service reference to the URL and use it in my compact framework application i get an "unauthorised" error.

i can create a winforms/webforms app and reference a library to set the username/password for the outgoing message and it works fine (library supplied by third party so i also cannot view the code).

the library is not compatible with the compact framework and it also requires the SoapExtension be specified in the app.config/web.config file which is also not present in the compact framework.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?                      Were you able to create SmartDeviceProject?

Comment: yes, im running windows mobile 6.5 with visual studio 2008 running on a win xp vm.  the mobile development side of things is fine and all works but im not able to figure out how i can override the outgoing soap message to amend the header.